# Qt embedded app probably closing with map: vt01 => fb0

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, banana-pi

I am running embedded qt application on Banana Pi with LCD attached. Application starts at boot up but first there is splash screen.

Script for splash screen

```
do_start () {
/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /root/logo.png
exit 0
}

case "$1" in
start|"")
do_start
;;
restart|reload|force-reload)
echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
exit 3
;;
stop)
# No-op
;;
status)
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
exit 3
;;
esac
```

After qt app starts with script:

```
do_start () {
#service ssh restart
/root/test3 -qws
reboot
exit 0
}

case "$1" in
start|"")
do_start
;;
restart|reload|force-reload)
echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
exit 3
;;
stop)
# No-op
;;
status)
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
exit 3
;;
esac
```

Application is working good, but after some time (idle time, where i am doing nothing with lcd and touch screen) on the screen appears message:

```
map: vt01 => fb0
```

I dont know where the problem is. Is this qt app problem? or is this linux problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Qt problem. It means, that your first virtual terminal (vt01) is mapped to your first framebuffer (fb0). The `clear` command can remove this message or use the VT100 erase screen sequence `<ESC>[2J`